# 'document.prodimage' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting Java script error while loading page in IE8 on Windows 7: `document.prodimage` is null or not an object.

I removed my dynamic proprietary code that functions as API calls to grab data, so areas that read: "" is where I dynamically grab stuff, like images & links, based on what product someone is looking at. Anyways, this is not the problem. Here it is:

```
<a rel="position:'inside',showTitle:false,adjustX:-4,adjustY:-4" href="">
    <img border="0" class="prodimage" id="prodimage" src="" width="200" height="200" alt="" onMouseover="document.prodimage.src='';" style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;display:block;"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant `window.prodimage`, as it's the `window` object that gets properties created on it for the elements with `id` values.

But typically, even though that works with all modern browsers (and quite a few old ones) and is becoming [specified behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), it's more common to use `getElementById` instead. For clarity, I'm not encouraging you to use the automatic globals, just saying what you were probably thinking of when using `document`.

In **your** case, though, since you're using an `onXYZ` event handler, just use `this`:

```
<a rel="position:'inside',showTitle:false,adjustX:-4,adjustY:-4" href="">
    <img border="0" class="prodimage" id="prodimage" src="" width="200" height="200" alt="" onMouseover="this.src='';" style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;display:block;"/>
    <!-- Change is here ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^        -->
</a>
```

I'm not sure I see why you want to clear the `src` attribute on mouse over, but...

Comment: I doubt that any modern browser creates properties as reference to elements by id/name! That was a bad idea in IE's document.all and no one want's that back. Can you prove that in a fiddle?

Comment: @metadings: Check your assumptions at the door, I didn't just make this up. **All** mainstream modern browsers do it, and again, it's now part of the spec (which I kindly linked). Try it yourself: http://jsbin.com/aBUCuLI/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/aBUCuLI/1/edit). Moreover, the answer in main didn't rely on that behavior, merely pointed out what the OP was probably thinking of.

Comment: well another bloat in the DOM. it seems that jS created globals take precedence, when you do `window['theDiv'] = ""` and then `<div id="theDiv" />` the property `window['theDiv']` keeps being the string

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the DOM works.

You need `document.getElementById('prodimage');`